# How can I reset my X configuration?

Tags: x11, display-settings

Typically, I connect my laptop to a 4k monitor via HDMI. A few months ago, I connected my laptop to a TV via HDMI. After disconnecting it, I can no longer use 4k on the monitor. I may have put the computer to sleep before disconnecting the TV, but I can't be sure. I've searched around the Internet, including Stack Exchange, but haven't found a solution.

When I connect the monitor, I have the option to use 4k, but if I select it, no signal is sent to the monitor. It seems like X really sees the new resolution; I can move my mouse way off in the direction of the monitor, it takes time to move it back. So X sees some desktop space over there.

The laptop is a Dell Precision 5530, with an NVidia Quadro P1000. I'm running Kubuntu 19.10 and the NVidia 440.100 driver. The monitor is an LG 27UD69P. The TV is a Samsung smart TV, but I don't have the model information handy.

Here is my xrandr output. eDP-1-1 is the laptop's built-in display. DP-1-3 is the HDMI connection.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  59.98    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01*   59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     30.00 +  25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00*   59.94    30.00    29.97  
   1920x1080i    60.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94
```